# Regex to match words starting with hyphen

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex which does all matches except one match.The PHP Code for the word match is:

```
$string = preg_replace("/\b".$wordToMatch."\b/","<span class='sp_err' style='background-color:yellow;'>".$wordToMatch."</span>",$string);
```

Here in the above regex when the $wordToMatch variable value becomes "-abc" and the $string value is "The word -abc should match and abc-abc should not match".With above regex it fails to catch "-abc".

- I want enhancement in the above regex so that it can catch "-abc" in $string,but if it tries to match "-abc" in "abc-abc" of $string it should not.

Comment: What about `/\B-abc\b/`?

Comment: Thanks...It does matching "-abc" but it does not matches the word without hyphen "abc" which was maching in previous regex["/\b".$wordToMatch."\b/"].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your keywords can have non-word characters on both ends you can rely on lookarounds for a whole word match:

```
"/(?<!\\w)".$wordToMatch."(?!\\w)/"
```

Here, `(?<!\w)` will make sure there is no word character before the word to match, and `(?!\w)` negative lookahead will make sure there is no word character *after* the word to match. These are *unambiguous subpatterns*, while `\b` meaning depends on the context.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yN6fA0/2) showing that `-abc` is not matched in `abc-abc` and matches if it is not enclosed with word characters.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/hOIy5i):

```
$wordToMatch = "-abc";
$re = "/(?<!\\w)" . $wordToMatch . "(?!\\w)/"; 
$str = "abc-abc -abc"; 
$subst = "!$0!"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result; // => abc-abc !-abc!
```

Comment: Thanks..but here it is also matching the "-abc" in the "abc-abc".That should not happen.

Comment: If the word $wordToMatch starts with hyphen i.e:"-answer" and if $string contains any independent word like "-answer"[not "question-answer"] , it should show match of independent word.

Comment: Will this regex will satisfy all the cases which i was matching in previous "/\b".$wordToMatch."\b/" regex?

Comment: Yes, because `\b` matches a word boundary, that is,  a place between a non-word character and a word character (also at the beginning and the end). However, these lookarounds have "static" meaning and will perform the same with any context.

Comment: Thank you so much...i have checked with most of the scenarios and it is working for all of them..thanks...

Comment: I have checked for all my scenarios..it is working fine ...but if i enters 'abc then it detects 'abc in the string...for that scenario only i does not want to catch the apostrophe at the beginning of the word...any suggessions?

Comment: I do not understand this requirement. If your keywords is `'abc`, you would like to find a whole word match (not inside the word characters). Or not? What does it mean "to catch the apostrophe" if your keyword has it? Change the keywords before passing to the regex then...

Comment: Ok...i can pass in this way that the word 'abc keyword will be changed before passing to the regex..for that which regex can i use to remove apostrophe from the keyword?